# Unbounded strictly increasing non-Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

My gut tells me that every strictly-increasing, non-Cauchy sequence should be unbounded. I've sketched out a simple proof that suggests that if it is not Cauchy then for some $m>n$ and some $\epsilon$:
$$x_m\geq x_n+\epsilon$$
Which can be easily used to deny the existence of a supremum. Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Given a strictly increasing sequence, if it is bounded then it converges and is therefore Cauchy. Therefore, if a strictly increasing sequence is not Cauchy, then it is not bounded. I think this is a simpler justification.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.